# How to test jQuery UI Dialog during headless execution

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jquery-ui-dialog, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

Our app uses [jQuery dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for modal popups. We're trying to write some unit tests for our javascript, and part of this is the creation of the dialogs. We're using Jasmine and the [Jasmine Maven plugin](http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/). When running the tests in a browser, it all works fine. However, when we trying to run a headless execution of the tests (`mvn jasmine:test`), the tests fail on the lines creating the dialog. There error looks something like this:

```
* TypeError: Cannot find function dialog in object [object Object].
```

The line this happens on is simply like this:

```
$(element).dialog(popupProperties);
```

If it helps, our pom.xml has this for the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <preloadSources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/jquery.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/jquery-ui.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/angular.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/lib/angular-mocks.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/lib/jasmine-fixture.js</source>
                </preloadSources>
                <jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/</jsSrcDir>
                <jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/unit/</jsTestSrcDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is there something we can do to get the headless execution working with the dialog stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what the problem was. Basically the `preloadSources` from our src directory were getting added twice to the spec runner. It would do all the `preoloadSources` first, and then add everything from the src directory. So, `jquery.js` got added a 2nd time under the 2nd `jquery-ui.js`, and thus it didn't know what `dialog` was. We fixed it by changing our pom.xml to the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <preloadSources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/${ivplugin.client.version}/jquery.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/${ivplugin.client.version}/jquery-ui.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/${ivplugin.client.version}/angular.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/lib/angular-mocks.js</source>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/lib/jasmine-fixture.js</source>
                </preloadSources>
                <jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/${ivplugin.client.version}/</jsSrcDir>
                <jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/unit/</jsTestSrcDir>
                <sourceExcludes>
                    <exclude>**/jquery.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/jquery-ui.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/angular.js</exclude>
                </sourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The `sourceExcludes` prevents it from getting added the 2nd time. This all seems like a bug with the plugin, but this allowed us to get around it.